# How to enable WCF Service to use .NET Core RC2?

Tags: .net, wcf, upgrade, legacy, .net-core

I have a legacy WCF service built with .NET 4.5.x

What do I need to do in order to make it use .NET Core?

Any replies will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37609795/745969) about the [WCF Connected Service Visual Studio Extension Preview for ASP.NET 5 Projects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/12/15/wcf-connected-service-visual-studio-extension-preview-for-asp-net-5-projects/)?

Comment: It is a VS 2015 extension helps add a reference to a WCF conneted service to ASP.NET MVC 5 web projects. But it does not upgrade or convert legacy WCF projects to WCF projects that would use .NET CORE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Writing WCF services on .Net Core is currently not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1200#issuecomment-222857224):

> Providing WCF Server support for .NET Core is on the radar.
>
> As you know, our current POR is to provide the WCF client-side libraries in .NET Core to enable UWP/ ASP.NET Core/.NET Core applications to call .NET Framework based WCF Services.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not exactly what you are looking for but you might find it useful.
 
[dotnetcorersi](https://github.com/imatitya/netcorersi/wiki) is a TCP based solution for remote service invocation in dotnet core framework.

Host your service

```
    // Initialize new instance of RemoteServiceContainer
    var container = new RemoteServiceContainer();

    // Register MyCustomService as IMyCustomService 
    container.RegisterService(typeof(IMyCustomService), new MyCustomService());

    // Open connection 
    container.Open(serverIp, port);
```

Initialize service proxy in client side

```
    // Create instance of ServiceChannel
    var servicesChannel = new ServiceChannel(serverIp, port);

    // Generate remote service proxy
    var proxy = servicesChannel.GetRemoteService<IMyCustomService>();
```

Use your service

```
    // Do some work in the server context
    proxy.DoSomething();
```